# Preventing google(search engines) to indexing specific view of my codeigniter website

Tags: codeigniter, robots.txt, codeigniter-url

I'm using following text in robots.text which resides in root of my website currently to hiding view.php from google.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /application/views/view.php
```

Am i doing it correct or i have to write controller path like following

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /index.php/mycontroller/function
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Pattle is right about the URL referencing as the folders are usually not indexed directly, they get indexed when they are found in a page, whereas the **application** folder shouldn't even be accessible via browser/internet. So thumbs up to:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /index.php/mycontroller/function
Disallow: /mycontroller/function
```

in case you remove ***"index.php"*** from ***config.php*** file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reference the **URL** rather than the path to the file.  So in your case the correct way is

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /index.php/mycontroller/function
```